# ¿Como utilizar documentViewer y ckEditor en primeFaces?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, java-ee

He creado un archivo pdf con iText y el plugin de javascript ckEditor, posteriormente cuando intento mostrarlo en el documentViewer de primefaces me manda el siguiente error:

> ckeditor.js:94 GET
>   http://localhost:8282/Channels/javax.faces.resource/ckeditor/config.js?ln=primefaces-extensions&v=6.0.0
>   404 (No Encontrado)

Por lo que veo el error es que no encuentra el plugin de la extensión ckEditor de primefaces, sin embargo no utilizó el plugin de primefaces si no que descargue el de javascript por que ese lo puedo personalizar.

Esto solo pasa cuando agrego el documentViewer de primefaces. 
He buscado por qué manda ese el error pero no encuentro en que momento o por qué busca la extensión de primefaces en lugar de mi plugin de javascript.

Comment: Si utilizas Maven puedes buscar la dependencia **Resources Ckeditor**, ¿no será ese el problema? La versión de PrimeFaces también la puedes personalizar con el archivo **config.js**

Comment: Intentare descargándolo desde Maven. Si utilizara la extensión de PrimeFaces como podria personalizar el archivo config.js si también la he descargado desde Maven.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el componente **ckEditor** de de **PrimeFaces** y personalizar la configuración de esta forma.

Componente de PrimeFaces:

```
<pe:ckEditor id="editorPlantilla" widgetVar="wEditorPlantilla" value="#{plantillaControl.plantillaSelected.texto}" width="100%" height="500px" skin="kama"
             toolbar="[['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', 'Undo', 'Redo'], 
             ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript'], 
             ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', 'Outdent', 'Indent', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv'], ['HorizontalRule'],
             ['JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock'], 
             ['Font', 'FontSize'], ['Table'], ['Maximize']]"
             contentsCss="#{resource['/css/plantillaContrato.css']}" customConfig="#{resource['/js/config.js']}"
             required="true" requiredMessage="Escriba el contenido de la plantilla" />
```

Este es el archivo **config.js** que yo he personalizado:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
    config.language = 'es';
    config.height = 300;
    config.toolbarCanCollapse = true;
    config.allowedContent = true;
    config.extraAllowedContent = 'span(*)';
    config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
    config.fontSize_sizes = '8/8pt;9/9pt;10/10pt;11/11pt;12/12pt;14/14pt;16/16pt;18/18pt;20/20pt;22/22pt;24/24pt;26/26pt;28/28pt;36/36pt;48/48pt';
};

CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function (ev) {
    // Take the dialog window name and its definition from the event data.
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;
    if (dialogName === 'table' || dialogName === 'tableProperties') {
        // Estilo propio
        var advTab = dialogDefinition.getContents('advanced');
        // Width por defecto
        var stylesField = advTab.get('advStyles');
        stylesField ['default'] = 'width: 100%';
        // Clase por defecto
        var styleClassesField = advTab.get('advCSSClasses');
        styleClassesField ['default'] = 'tabla';
        //styleClassesField ['hidden'] = true;

        var info = dialogDefinition.getContents('info');
        var defAncho = info.get('txtWidth');
        defAncho['default'] = '100%';
        //defAncho['hidden'] = true;

        var defHeader = info.get('selHeaders');
        defHeader['default'] = 'row';
        //defHeader['hidden'] = true;
    }
});

CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (ev) {
    var blockTags = ['div', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6', 'p', 'pre', 'li', 'blockquote', 'ul', 'ol',
        'table', 'thead', 'tbody', 'tfoot', 'td', 'th', 'tr'];

    for (var i = 0; i < blockTags.length; i++) {
        ev.editor.dataProcessor.writer.setRules(blockTags[i], {
            indent: false,
            breakBeforeOpen: true,
            breakAfterOpen: false,
            breakBeforeClose: false,
            breakAfterClose: true
        });
    }
});
```

Es solo un ejemplo.

Comment: Te molesto con otra duda, al editor del plugin puedo agregarle elementos con el método insertHtml(), sin embargo cuando intento hacer lo mismo con el editor de PrimeFaces me arroja un error diciendo que el método no existe. ¿La forma de obtener el editor instanciado en PrimeFaces es la misma a como lo hago en el plugin?

Comment: Creo que en ese caso tendrías que utilizar el atributo `widgetVar` del componente y a la hora de instanciarlo sería con PF('widgetVarNombre')